# SPI hookup to ATmega644

Tags: atmega, spi

I'm trying to hookup a DS1302 to an ATmega644. The DS1302 pin 6 is a SPI I/O port but the ATmega644 has a MOSI on pin PB5 and a MISO on pin PB6.

How do I go about hooking it up?

This is my current circuit.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Have you considered a 2-position or DPST DIP switch?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem statement: DS1302 is a three-wire-interface (TWI) but isn't actually SPI. Thus, all you need is pin 6 to any available GPIO pin, pin 7 supplied from any pin with a timer output, and Chip Enable (pin 5) fed from another GPIO on the Atmel MCU. The rest is code.

Comment: It is possible to connect a DS1302 to a SPI bus though. All you need to do is shut up MOSI when reading.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh TWI is Atmel's informal name for I²C.

Comment: As a side node: don't forget decoupling caps at the AVR's VCC pin.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde Yes, but the Maxim part isn't SPI, just similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use SPI for just any three-wire interface. In SPI there's no separate reading vs writing mode. Bits get exchanged in both directions at every clock, so you really need a separate wire to MISO if you need bidirectional communication.

In this case, I would argue that it will work even though you're using the same pins for your ISP port. However, in your code you won't be able to use the hardware SPI interface.

That is fine, though. You'll have to bit-bang communication with the DS1302, but speed is not critical for this application, is my guess.

Comment: So I should be able to take pin 5, 6 and 7 from the DS1302 and connect them to any pins on the ATmega644 and bit-bang them to talk to the DS1302?

Comment: Indeed, any of the general pins would do, even those that have double functions like the SPI pins you have selected now.